# How do I sort a Queryset according to a list?

Tags: python, django

For example, I do this:

```
m.objects.filter (id__in = [3,1,8])
```

And it is necessary that the elements in the queryset go in order, that is, first id = 3, then id = 1, then id = 8, etc.

But in the end, you need a queryset, not a list!

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? even if you managed this it isn't manageable when you a production and other databases for example... at the very least you're better off making an ordering_weight field and order by on that

Comment: It wouldn’t be particularly query efficient but you could loop through your list of ids and pull each one individually and add it to a list. But as mentioned before you probably just want some sort of ordering weight field instead.